# WPF MVVM Dependency Property raised from a UserControl don't go to the User Control container

Tags: c#, wpf

If someone can help me before I go crazy.
I have a User Control who contains a ListBox
I would like to add a property for the SelectedItem to the UserControl, so the parent can get it.
So I used a DependencyProperty

UserControl (VersionList.xaml):

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="PcVueLauncher.Controls.VersionsList"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:PcVueLauncher.Converters"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PcVueLauncher.Controls"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:Background="white"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="0"
            Padding="10"
            Text="Versions" />
        <ListBox
            Grid.Row="1"
            d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Versions}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVersion}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="5,5,10,5"
                            Text="{Binding VersionName}" />
                        <Button
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Padding="5"
                            Command="{Binding RemoveVersionCommand}"
                            Content="Remove"
                            Visibility="{Binding CanBeRemoved, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl Associated ViewModel (VersionListViewModel)

```
namespace PcVueLauncher.ViewModels.Controls
{
    public class VersionsListViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        private List<VersionPcVue> _versions;
        public List<VersionPcVue> Versions
        {
            get
            {
                return _versions;
            }
            set
            {
                _versions = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Versions));
            }
        }

        private VersionPcVue _selectedVersion;
        public VersionPcVue SelectedVersion
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedVersion;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedVersion = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedVersion));
            }
        }


        public ICommand RemoveVersionCommand { get; }


        public VersionsListViewModel()
        {
            List<VersionPcVue> versionPcVues = new()
            {
                new VersionPcVue{VersionName="V15"},
                new VersionPcVue{VersionName="V12"}
            };
            Versions = versionPcVues;
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl code behind (VersionList.cs):

```
public partial class VersionsList : UserControl
{
    public VersionsList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public VersionPcVue SelectedVersion
    {
        get { return (VersionPcVue)GetValue(SelectedVersionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedVersionProperty, value); }
    }

    //Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedVersion.This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedVersionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedVersion",
            typeof(VersionPcVue),
            typeof(VersionsList),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        defaultValue: null,
        flags: FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure,
        propertyChangedCallback: new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectionChanged)));


    private static void OnSelectionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.CoerceValue(SelectedVersionProperty);
    }
}


    // Register a dependency property with the specified property name,
    // property type, owner type, property metadata, and callbacks.
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedVersionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    name: "SelectedVersion",
    propertyType: typeof(VersionPcVue),
    ownerType: typeof(VersionsList),
    typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        defaultValue: null,
        flags: FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure,
        propertyChangedCallback: new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectionChanged)
    ));



    private static void OnSelectionChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        depObj.CoerceValue(SelectedVersionProperty);
    }
```

In the HomeView which contains the UserControl, I have this :

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="PcVueLauncher.Views.HomeView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:PcVueLauncher.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PcVueLauncher.Views"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:PcVueLauncher.ViewModels"
    d:Background="White"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodels:HomeViewModel}"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <Controls:VersionsList
            x:Name="test"
            Grid.Column="0"
            DataContext="{Binding VersionsListViewModel}"
            SelectedVersion="{Binding DataContext.SelectedVersion, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And in the associated ViewModel (HomeViewModel)

```
   public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private IProjectService _projectService;

        private VersionPcVue _selectedVersion;
        public VersionPcVue SelectedVersion
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedVersion;
            }   
            set
            {
                _selectedVersion = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedVersion));
            }
        }

        private VersionPcVue _test1;
        public VersionPcVue Test1
        {
            get
            {
                return _test1;
            }
            set
            {
                _test1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Test1));
            }
        }

        private string _test;
        public string Test
        {
            get
            {
                return _test;
            }
            set
            {
                _test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Test));
            }
        }

        private VersionsListViewModel versionsListViewModel;
        public VersionsListViewModel VersionsListViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return versionsListViewModel;
            }
            set
            {
                versionsListViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(VersionsListViewModel));
            }
        }

        public HomeViewModel(IProjectService projectService)
        {

            _projectService = projectService;

            VersionsListViewModel = new();
        }
    }
```

When I change the selected item from my user control, nothing happens in the HomeViewModel.
I thought about a binding error, but to try, I changed this

```
   SelectedVersion="{Binding DataContext.SelectedVersionnnnnnn, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And Visual Studio tells me that the SelectedVersionnnnn does not exist in HomeViewModel.

Why can't I get back the Selected Item back to the SelectedVersion  property of my HomeViewModel.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If your code isn't working you should always post the full context in order to allow a proper code review. This is crucial. As we don't know your project, we can only fix what we can review. [How do I ask a good question?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please, show at least the DataContext of the UserControl (so that we can validate your bindings) and how the ListBox is wired to the dependency property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `VersionList.xaml` :

```xml
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVersion}" ...
```

This only bind `ListBox.SelectedItem` to `{DataContext}.SelectedVersion`. Then when a item is selected, the dependency property `VersionList.SelectedVersion` isn't updated.

---

Solution 1 : By view model (without dependency property)

I think you mixed-up because you try to use a dependency property that is complex. A easy way is to use directly the view model without dependency property.

In `VersionsList.cs`, remove `SelectedVersionProperty` and `SelectedVersion` members.

Keep `VersionList.xaml` with :

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="PcVueLauncher.Controls.VersionsList" />
...
    <ListBox
        ...
        ItemsSource="{Binding Versions}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVersion}">
...
</UserControl>
```

So `ListBox.SelectedItem` is bind to `ListBox.DataContext.SelectedVersion`. If `ListBox.DataContext` is `VersionsListViewModel`, then `ListBox.SelectedItem` is bind to `VersionsListViewModel.SelectedVersion`.

In the parent controls `HomeView`, it only need to pass a `VersionsListViewModel` to the `VersionList.DataContext` :

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="PcVueLauncher.Views.HomeView"
...
    <Controls:VersionsList DataContext="{Binding VersionsListViewModel}" />
...
</UserControl>
```

So `HomeView.VersionsList.ListBox.SelectedItem` is bind `HomeView.DataContext.VersionsListViewModel.SelectedVersion`. If `HomeView.DataContext` is `HomeViewModel`, then `HomeView.VersionsList.ListBox.SelectedItem` is bind `HomeViewModel.VersionsListViewModel.SelectedVersion`.

Finally, you can remove the member `HomeViewModel.SelectedVersion` and use `HomeViewModel.VersionsListViewModel.SelectedVersion`.

If you want keep the member `HomeViewModel.SelectedVersion`, then you need to redirect `HomeViewModel.SelectedVersion` to `HomeViewModel.VersionsListViewModel.SelectedVersion` in `HomeViewModel.cs` :

```cs
public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private VersionsListViewModel versionsListViewModel;
    public VersionsListViewModel VersionsListViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return versionsListViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if(versionsListViewModel != null)
                versionsListViewModel.PropertyChanged -= VersionsListViewModel_PropertyChanged;
            versionsListViewModel = value;
            if(versionsListViewModel != null)
                versionsListViewModel.PropertyChanged += VersionsListViewModel_PropertyChanged;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(VersionsListViewModel));
        }
    }

    public VersionPcVue SelectedVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return versionsListViewModel.SelectedVersion;
        }   
        set
        {
            versionsListViewModel.SelectedVersion = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedVersion));
        }
    }

    void VersionsListViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Propagate the property changed SelectedVersion
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.PropertyName) || e.PropertyName == nameof(VersionsListViewModel.SelectedVersion))
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedVersion));
    }
}
```

The trick is when `HomeViewModel.VersionsListViewModel.SelectedVersion` is changed, also notify that `HomeViewModel.SelectedVersion` is changed.

---

Solution 2 : By dependency property

In sumary, you want when a item is selected that set the selected item in `VersionsList.SelectedVersion`, then you just need to bind `ListBox.SelectedItem` to `VersionsList.SelectedVersion`.

First, add the dependency property `SelectedVersion` in `VersionList.cs` :

```cs
public partial class VersionsList : UserControl
{
    public VersionsList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public VersionPcVue SelectedVersion
    {
        get { return (VersionPcVue)GetValue(SelectedVersionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedVersionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedVersionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SelectedVersion",
            typeof(VersionPcVue),
            typeof(VersionsList),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                defaultValue: null,
                flags: FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure
            )
        );

    public List<VersionPcVue> Versions
    {
        get { return (List<VersionPcVue>)GetValue(VersionsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VersionsProperty, value); }
    }
 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VersionsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Versions",
            typeof(List<VersionPcVue>),
            typeof(VersionsList),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                defaultValue: null,
                flags: FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure
            )
        );
}
```

In `VersionList.xaml` :

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="PcVueLauncher.Controls.VersionsList" />
...
    <ListBox
        ...
        ItemsSource="{Binding Versions}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVersion, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}">
...
</UserControl>
```

`{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` indicate the binding refer to the element to which the template, here `VersionsList`.

To use the control :

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="PcVueLauncher.Views.HomeView"
...
    <Controls:VersionsList
        Versions="{Binding VersionsListViewModel.Versions}" 
        SelectedVersion="{Binding SelectedVersion}"/>
...
</UserControl>
```

> Versions is also changed to harmonize the binding strategy.

Finally, you can remove the member `VersionsListViewModel.SelectedVersion` (or use the trick below).

---

What to choose?

With dependency property, the control isn't link to view model class. I will use this to develop a library to reuse in many application.

With view model, the control expect specific members in the data context. I will use this in the application solution.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see it. I changed it but still not working

Comment: @StéphanF - can you edit your question to add more information like asked in the question's comments?

Comment: @StéphanF - Did you try the suggested xaml edit from this answer?

Comment: In my HomeViewModel I change SelectedVersion to  Test1 and put your suggested code (SelectedVersion="{Binding Test1}". But it tells me that Test1 does not exist in context VersionListViewModel

Comment: I used the Dependency Property solution and with the correction of errors in your provided code, it works.
In List View, I did that
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=VersionsItemsSource}"
SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=SelectedVersionItem}">    
I need to understand why it works :-)
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix several issues:

1. Don't explicitly call `DependencyObject.CoerceValue` from the property changed callback. It is invoked automatically by the dependency property system - before the property changed callback.
2. Your property does not affect the layout. For the sake of a better performance, don't set the `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure` flag as it will force a complete layout pass every time the property changes, which is unnecessary in your case. The `ListBox.SelectedItem` has no influence on the layout of your control. Instead you should consider to configure the property to bind two way by default by setting the `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault` flag.
3. a) Bind internals of a `Control` to the control's properties and not to the `DataContext`. Otherwise your control becomes inconvenient to handle (and to write). For example, if you change the `DataContext` or rename properties on the object returned by the `DataContext`, you are forced to rewrite the internal bindings to address the new object structure/property names.

   b) This means you have to remove all internal  `DataContext` bindings and introduce a dependency property for each. For example, remove the `ListBox.ItemsSource` binding to the `VersionsListViewModel.Versions` property and introduce a e.g., `VersionsItemsSource` dependency property instead.
4. For example in `HomeView`: define all `DataContext` related `Binding` relative to the actual `DataContext` of the `UserControl` (or `FrameworkElement` in general) instead of starting a traversal (using `Binding.RelativeSource`) to find the parent's `DataContext` that is the same as the binding target's `DataContext`. It's pointless and only shows that you have not understood how Binding works.

## Fixes

### 1 & 2 & 3b

**VersionList.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class VersionsList : UserControl
{
    public VersionPcVue SelectedVersionItem
    {
        get => (VersionPcVue)GetValue(SelectedVersionItemProperty); 
        set => SetValue(SelectedVersionItemProperty, value); 
    }
    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedVersionItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedVersionItem",
        typeof(VersionPcVue),
        typeof(VersionsList),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(VersionPcVue), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnSelectedVersionChanged));

    public IList VersionsItemsSource
    {
        get => (IList)GetValue(VersionsItemsSourceProperty); 
        set => SetValue(VersionsItemsSourceProperty, value); 
    }
    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VersionsItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "VersionsItemsSource",
        typeof(IList),
        typeof(VersionsList),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public VersionsList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static void OnSelectedVersionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {        
    }
}
```

### 3a

**VersionList.xaml**
When authoring a `Control`, always bind to properties of the control instead to properties of the `DataContext`:

```xml
<UserControl>
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="0"
            Padding="10"
            Text="Versions" />
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1"
                 d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=VersionsItemsSource}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=SelectedVersionItem}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="5,5,10,5"
                            Text="{Binding VersionName}" />
                        <Button
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Padding="5"
                            Command="{Binding RemoveVersionCommand}"
                            Content="Remove"
                            Visibility="{Binding CanBeRemoved, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### 4

**HomeView.xaml**
Note that the `DataContext` of the `VersionsList` control is referencing a `VersionsListViewModel` instance. You must adjust all bindings accordingly:

```xml
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Controls:VersionsList x:Name="test"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               DataContext="{Binding VersionsListViewModel}"
                               VersionsItemsSource="{Binding Versions}"
                               SelectedVersionItem="{Binding SelectedVersion}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### Remarks

> "Why can't I get back the Selected Item back to the SelectedVersion
> property of my HomeViewModel."

Given your current class design and control configuration, your `VersionsList` control binds to the `VersionsListViewModel.SelectedVersion` property. It's not clear what you really want at this point.
Either delegate the value manually by letting the `HomeViewModel` listen to `VersionsListViewModel.SelectedVersion` property changes or drop related properties from the `VersionsListViewModel` and bind to the `HomeViewModel.SelectedVersion` directly. A view model class per view/control will result in bad class design/code most of the time. Creating separate classes should be based on different considerations like responsibilities.
And then you always want to avoid duplicate code (like  properties and logic): instead of *copying* you *move* code to separate classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BionicCode. 
In fact, what I want is when I change the SelectedItem in the UserControl, I want also to be notify in the HomeViewModel by the SelectedVersion property of the HomeViewModel.
But probably I understood everything wrong. Does it mean that what I did is the complete opposite of what I want?
I thought, that like for a classic ListBox, for example, in my HomeView, and bind the SelectedItem to a SelectedItem property of the ViewModel, when the selected item changes (by cliking on it), the property of the ViewModel is set to this new value.
I still have to learn I think

Comment: When you bind to HomeViewModel then it is updated via data binding. If you bind to VersionsListViewModel then HomeViewModel is not updated via data binding because you are not binding to it, if this makes sense.

Comment: The question is, why do you have a VersionsListViewModel in the first place if all the data is needed in HomeViewModel? Either move related properties from VersionsListViewModel  to HomeViewModel (SelectedVersion and Versions) or move the logic that requires the SelectedVersion from HomeViewModel to VersionsListViewModel. You have to fix your classes for sure.

Comment: for your help – 
Stéphan F
 5 hours ago   Delete
You're right. I'm thinking the wrong way. But in some case, perhaps :-) . Let me think about that. But anyway, thanks a lot for your help and explanaition